# Matplotlib plot bar, float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am showing relevant part of the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tacf = pd.DataFrame(data_acf)
print (type(tacf))
plt.bar(tacf,height=2.0)
plt.show()
```

Output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  File "/home/jh/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 351, in set_linewidth
    self._linewidth = float(w)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

If I go for tacf.head

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of            0
0   1.000000
1   0.942361
2   0.863303
3   0.794420
4   0.727603
5   0.671579
6   0.622612
7   0.570949
8   0.529410
9   0.497035
10  0.485163
11  0.479443
12  0.461094
13  0.444726
14  0.436634
```

I am confused with bars args and kwargs.
Should I convert dataframe to different type or..?

How to plot dataframe as a bar with Matplotlib?

Comment: Does tacf.head() return any data?

Comment: `tacf.head()`, not `tacf.head`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have pandas dataframe, you can u its plotting method:

```
tacf.plot(kind='bar')
```

Result for your data:

[image]

This is equivalent to:

```
plt.bar(tacf.index, tacf.iloc[:, 0])
plt.legend(tacf.columns)
```